# Magento 2 how to add Fonts?

Tags: magento2, fonts

I tested my site speed on **Gtmetrix** and it showed fonts rendering through

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600,700|Roboto:400,400i,700 .
```

And it is called in theme layout as -`css src="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600,700|Roboto:400,400i,700" src_type="url"`  .
I  want to download and store the fonts locally and render them .
How to do this ?

Comment: you can add font files to your local theme directory. `app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/fonts`

Comment: check from here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to difine css in `default_head_blocks.xml` like this

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <css src="css/custome.css" /> 
</head>
</page>
```

and then put your font css file in this path

```
app\design\frontend\Vendor\CustomTheme\web\fonts\custom.css
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Add font files to your local theme directory. For example,

```
app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/fonts.
```

> 2. If you build a theme using the Magento UI library, declare the font
>      by adding the .lib-font-face mixin to the

`app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/css/source/_typography.less`

```
.lib-font-face(
         @family-name:'<any_font_name>',
         @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/<path_to_font_file>',
         @font-weight: <font_weight>,
         @font-style: <font_style>
     );
```

**After This Step Follow This Command :-**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: And how to call these fonts in default_head_blocks.xml?

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: dont need to define less file